# What is the difference between appendTo and writeTo in NLog?

Tags: .net, logging, nlog

I've seen a lot of sample configurations of NLog. I noticed that some of the loggers specified the target by using the `appendTo` attribute while others used the `writeTo` attribute.

I could not find any documentation explaining when to use one over the other. And I couldn't spot any obvious pattern.

I thought maybe it depended on the type of target, whether it was a file or console or something. But I've seen it use interchangeably in both cases.

For example in this StackOverflow thread you can see the examples all use `writeTo` exclusively:

[Most useful NLog configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091606/most-useful-nlog-configurations)

The second answer though uses `appendTo`.

This other question includes one of each in it's sample code:

[How to get NLog to write to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008093/how-to-get-nlog-to-write-to-database)

Are they interchangeable? Aliases for each other? Or are there specific cases when do use which?

Comment: The answer is correct IMO so please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

> Are `writeTo` and `appendTo` aliases for each other?

Yes they are the same in the NLog logging-rules.

Comment: and both can be still used in NLog 4. If you define both in your config, the `appendTo` will be used.